# How to use simplexml_load_string in PHP to get innertext without embedded tags?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I found a [freely available data dump of USPTO patent data in XML format](https://bulkdata.uspto.gov/). Part of the XML for most of the patents has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v45-2014-04-03.dtd" [ ]>
<us-patent-grant lang="EN" dtd-version="v4.5 2014-04-03" file="US09226443-20160105.XML" status="PRODUCTION" id="us-patent-grant" country="US" date-produced="20151221" date-publ="20160105">
  ...
  <claims>
    ...
    <claim id="CLM-00015" num="00015">
      <claim-text>15. The system of <claim-ref idref="CLM-00013">claim 13</claim-ref>, wherein ...</claim-text>
    </claim>
  </claims>
</us-patent-grant>
```

When I execute the PHP `simplexml_load_string` function on the XML, the `<claim-ref idref="CLM-00013">claim 13</claim-ref>` part goes away and I'm left with the following for the claim text:

```
15. The system of , wherein ...
```

I tried executing the `simplexml_load_string` function as follows:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlTxt, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

But it didn't change anything.
What do I need to do in order to get the text within the `claim-ref` tags to be retained as part of the CDATA within the `claim-text` tags? Please note that I don't need to retain the actual `claim-ref` tags, just the text within them.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the `claim-ref` element to be appear in whole (tags, attributes, and all) in your output, or do you want just the text content of the `claim-ref` element to appear in your output?

Comment: Just the text. I've modified my question to reflect that. Thank you for asking.

Comment: Just to confirm, this has nothing to do with CDATA, just nested nodes. The keyword you're more likely to find helpful in searches is "inner text" (or "innerText").

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wasn't sure how to best word the question though. I have since edited it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is no CDATA section in your example XML. A CDATA section looks like this in XML:

```
<foo><![CDATA[<bar>text</bar>]]></foo>
```

The CDATA section is a single text node in this case. It is compareable to:

```
<foo>&lt;bar&gt;text&lt;/bar&gt;</foo>
```

If you need the text content of a SimpleXMLElement (including it's descendants) you can convert it into a DOM node. The DOMElement::$textContent property provides it.

```
$patentGrant = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$node = dom_import_simplexml($patentGrant->claims->claim->{'claim-text'});

var_dump($node->textContent);
```

Output:

```
string(39) "15. The system of claim 13, wherein ..."
```

Or you use `DOMXpath::evaluate()`, without SimpleXML at all:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(/us-patent-grant/claims/claim/claim-text)'));
```

Comment: This is more complicated than what I wanted, but it solves my problem. Thank you.